# I have downloaded nodejs for react but when my powershell open to install external tools it gives error shown in the image:-

Tags: node.js, reactjs, powershell, ssl, tls1.2

[screenshoto of window powershell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hoO4.png)
I have tried to change my server to tls12 but nothing happens .
I do not what to do with this error . I am a beginner.

Comment: What did you type in powershell ?

Comment: the software ask to install external tools .I checked the box after the installation it open commandprompt .I enter then powershell open and shown this error.

Comment: Go to nodejs website and download the node application according to your operating system , after the installation you find it installed npm package manager with it ..check it by typing npm -v

Comment: you can most likely ignore it. chocolatey is not required for node to work

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

as described [here](https://blog.pauby.com/post/force-powershell-to-use-tls-1-2/) or [here](https://chocolatey.org/blog/remove-support-for-old-tls-versions).